# dell xps 13 9360 ubuntu external monitor stopped working usb c

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, external-display, dell-xps, usb-c

since a firmware update my external screen stopped being recognized. any way to debug this?

more info:

- I have only one hdmi-usb c adapter so can't experiment with a different one (but this one has worked for me in the past)
- changing cables did not help
- changing screens did not help
- I'm using ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Try reducing the resolution of the second monitor using screen , it is apparently an issue with ubuntu graphics driver.